# Calling a controller create() method for multiple objects from one controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel so here goes:
I am creating a page for a user to register an account for his company and enter the payment method and her own login credentials. So this one page will create a Company, a User and a Payment record. The page calls the RegisterController method in Laravel.

However, each of the three objects' create methods are defined within their own controllers. Is it valid (or even good practice) to call other controller methods from within a controller like so **(some boilerplate code is missing below...I just want to get my point across)**

```
class RegisterController extends Controller {

  //boilerplate code.....

  protected function create(Request $request) {
    //Create the company
    $objCompany = CompanyController->create($request);   //gets created first since it is 'top level'
    
    //now create the user:
    $objUser = UserController->create($request,$objCompany->id);  //Company ID is FK in User

   //Create the paymentMethod
   $objPaymentMethod = PaymentMethodController->create($request,$objCompany->id);  //Company ID is FK in PaymentMethod
   }//end create()

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... I would say you should refactor the code for creating these different entities out of the controllers they are in, then you can have the controllers call the code they need and this particular controller can call the code for creating the other entities without touching the other controller

Comment: Typically no, you wouldn't call one controller from another. For what you're attempting it looks like you want to use Models.

Answer (score 0):

See rather than calling distinct controllers for table creation try to store the data directly to distinct tables from one controller itself.
like this

public function store(Request $request)
{
$data = request()->validate([
...
]);

```
    $users = new User;
    $users->name = $request->name;
    $users->ltname = $request->lname;
    $users->dob = $request->dob;
    $users->bgroup = $request->bgroup;
    $users->email = $request->email;
    $users->phone = $request->phone;
    $users->district = $request->district;
    $users->country = $request->country;
    $users->state = $request->state;
    $users->city = $request->city;
    $users->add = $request->add;
    $users->pincode = $request->pincode;
    $users->password = Hash::make(request('password'));
    $users->type = 'Service Center';
    $users->save();

    $posts = new Post;
    $posts->user_id = $users->id;
    $posts->fname = $request->fname;
    $posts->phone1 = $request->phone1;
    $posts->email1 = $request->email1;
    $posts->add2 = $request->add2;
    $posts->pincode1 = $request->pincode1;
    $posts->district1 = $request->district1;
    $posts->city1 = $request->city1;
    $posts->state1 = $request->state1;
    $posts->country1 = $request->country1;
    $posts->cmp_id = $request->cmp_id . $users->id;
    $posts->gst = $request->gst;
    $posts->badd = $request->badd;
    $posts->badd2 = $request->badd2;
    $posts->save();

    $subscribe = new Subscription;
    $subscribe->user_id = $users->id;
    $subscribe->post_id = $posts->id;
    $subscribe->offer_id = $request->m_option_1;
    $subscribe->trial_start_date = $offers->of_start_date;
    $subscribe->trial_end_date = $offers->of_end_date;
    $subscribe->pck_name = $offers->pck_id;
    $subscribe->valid_to = $offers->validity;
    $subscribe->type = $offers->of_type;
    $subscribe->save();

    $transactions = new Transactions;
    $transactions->user_id = $users->id;
    $transactions->post_id = $posts->id;
    $transactions->ddl_payment = $request->ddl_payment;
    $transactions->txt_ac = $request->txt_ac;
    $transactions->txt_amount = $request->txt_amount;
    $transactions->txt_dat = $request->txt_dat;
    $transactions->txt_ref = $request->txt_ref;
    $transactions->save();
    return redirect('/show');
}
```

Here the data which I'm accepting from the form is been stored in four tables users, post, subscription & transaction.